# IOS In App Purchase max quantity

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, in-app-purchase

I am developing an IOS app using Cordova. The user can purchase credits that can be used later. I am using In-App Purchase for the credit purchase using cc.fovea.cordova.purchase plugin.
In my app user can enter how many credits he wants to buy. Depending on that credit price is set.

Like:

1. 1-25 credits: $10
2. 26-50 credits: $8
3. 50+ credits: $6

I have created different Consumable In-App Purchases in Itunes for each price range.
Depending on user input I am sending which IAP to buy and how many quantity.
But the problem is I am not able to buy more than 10 quantity at a time [Sandbox].

Is there any solution to buy more than 10 quantity at a time?

Also Is there any alternative to In-App Purchase that can be used to fulfill my requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than purchasing multiple instances of a product it is more typical to have multiple products that each are a different quantity. So one product that is 1 credit, another that is 10, another that is 25 etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, that's a solution but the problem is that I need to create products for each quantity and it's huge. Also, all price range will not be available on Itunes.

Comment: You typically don’t create each individual value, just selected values. 1,5,10,25,50,100,250 and so on. If someone wants 11 credits then they can buy 10 & 1 or get a better price and buy 25

Comment: In my app, a user can input how many credits he wants to buy. Then I am checking which product belongs to this price range and sending buy request for this product with quantity.

Comment: Ok, but you have to work within the limitations of what IAP lets you do. You can only purchase 10 of an item at a time

Comment: Is there any option to increase the quantity?
Is there any alternative to IAP to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the maximum quantity for an in-app purchase is ten (10) units. See: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpayment/1506077-quantity)

However, as the developer, you can define what those units are. For example, to achieve something very similar to your preferred pricing strategy, you could define in-app products as follows:

- Single credit: $9.99
- 5 credits: $49.99
- 25 credits: $199.99
- 50 credits: $299.99

Users can then purchase the number of credits they need while receiving a discount for bulk purchase of credits.

Comment: It's a solution but not totally fulfill the requirement. User can't buy his preferred credits like 6, 10, 20 etc.
Is there any alternative payment method to solve my requirement?

Comment: For in-app purchases, Apple is the only game in town. Any alternative would need to be outside the app, perhaps web based.

Comment: I have an existing website and I am trying to implement the same functionality in App also.
So, if you can provide any other alternative that will be great.

Comment: Apple simply does not allow in-app purchase outside of its store.